# Build application on android that use Nodejs

Tags: android, node.js, webserver

First of all i would like to mention that i am newbie on nodejs.
I have the above challenge and i am trying to find a solution:

I would like to create a nodejs web app on an android phone with 3g, that i want to hit my web page from a browser outside the phone.

The code i have already install on my phone is :

```
var http = require('http');
http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
  res.end('Hello World\n');
}).listen(3000, "127.0.0.1");
console.log('Server running at http://127.0.0.1: 3000/');
```

and runs ok from my phone. But of course i cannot hit the webpage from a browser outside the phone.

I would appreciate a lot any kind of help - suggestions

**Edit**
I have change the ip to 0.0.0.0 and port 8080 and the problem occurs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered, unfortunately, that the problem is on 3g network. Every cell phone does not have a unique external ip (as pc through modem) but connects to internet through an ip of the 3g/4g provider. This approach would work easily on ipv6 protocol but ipv6 is not supported from most of phones. 
So the cell phone is very hard to work as web server. It can be done(teamviewer did) but it is a hard work and i do not have all the appropriate knowledge. (Thats the situation with 3g providers in greece)

Answer (score 0):

You have to use hybrid mobile framework for this Try `Ionic framework`that helps you to build application

Comment: i will but initially i am trying to hit just a simple page, that i cant do that. I do not think tha is mater of framework.

Comment: you have to use any framwork or cordova to simple converting your web application into android app

Comment: As i mention, i do not want to create an app that can be used from phone. I want to create an app **on** phone that can be used from other devices. The phone would work as a "webserver".

Comment: I think the matter is not why but how :) (i have a robotic project to implement)

Comment: The way and technique is very important and it depends upon your requirements

Comment: In initially the only requirement is to view a simple hello world webpage on any machine by hit the phone ip, which i am watching it only from the my phone that node runs.